# "Cursor To Selected" - Not centering correctly, What's going on?

Tags: 3d-cursor

I'm completely stumped over something so simple. I could work around it, but I want to know what's happening since it feels like a Blender bug.

I have 4 verts selected, and I want to move the cursor to the centre. I press SHIFT-S, "Cursor To Selected", and as you can see it's off by a fair bit:

[image: Cursor not centered]

If I then do a subdivide instead, I get the correct center point:

[image: Subdivision]

Anyone have any idea what's going on?

Edit: Added blend file:

https://pasteall.org/blend/18c2d4852f8b4c57b3b20e843047b933

Comment: Hello :). Tried it with your file, works just fine for me.

Comment: What version of Blender did you open it with? I just updated from 2.83.5 to 2.83.7 and the problem is still there for me.

Comment: Oh, this is interesting. It doesn't work in 2.83 (just like you described). But works fine in 2.9.

Comment: Reporting as a bug under 2.83, thanks for helping me narrow down the problem.